# X264 : How to access NAL units from encoder?

Tags: c, video-streaming, h.264, x264, libx264

When I call

```
frame_size = x264_encoder_encode(encoder, &nals, &i_nals, &pic_in, &pic_out);
```

and subsequently write each NAL to a file like this:

```
     if (frame_size >= 0)
     {
        int i;
        int j;

        for (i = 0; i < i_nals; i++)
        {
           printf("******************* NAL %d (%d bytes) *******************\n", i, nals[i].i_payload);
           fwrite(&(nals[i].p_payload[0]), 1, nals[i].i_payload, fid);
        }
     }
```

then I get this

[image: Beginning of NAL file]

My questions are:

1) Is it normal that there's readable parameters in the beginning of the file?

2) How do I configure the X264 encoder so that the encoder returns frames that I can send via UDP without the packet getting fragmented (size must be below 1390 or somewhere around that).

3) With the x264.exe I pass in these options:

```
"--threads 1 --profile baseline --level 3.2 --preset ultrafast --bframes 0 --force-cfr --no-mbtree --sync-lookahead 0 --rc-lookahead 0 --keyint 1000 --intra-refresh"
```

How do I map those to the settings in the X264 parameters structure ? (x264_param_t)

4) I have been told that the x264 static library doesn't support bitmap input to the encoder and that I have to use libswscale for conversion of the 24bit RGB input bitmap to YUV2. The encoder, supposedly, only takes YUV2 as input? Is this true? If so, how do I build libswscale for the x264 static library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes. x264 includes the automatically. Its an SEI slice, and you can throw it away if you want.

2) set i_slice_max_size = 1390

3) Take a look at x264_param_t in x264.h. The settings are fairly self explanatory. As for setting the profile and preset call `int x264_param_apply_profile( x264_param_t *, const char *profile )` and `int x264_param_default_preset( x264_param_t *, const char *preset, const char *tune )`

4) Yes, it is true, I want lying when I said that. Look online/on stack overflow there are a million resources on compiling ffmpeg. In fact if you compiled x264 with avcodec support you already have it on your system.

5) Yes!, you should be a good stack overflow citizen and up vote and accept answers form people who donate there free time and knowledge (which takes years to acquire) to helping you.

Comment: Thank you!! I appreciate your answers as you seem to be very knowledgeable about x264. I wasn't able to vote on your previous answers as they were comments (and not answers)...but I voted on your answer here :-) When I set i_slice_max_size to 1390 the encoder call results in an exception. Could you give me an example of how the parameters should be set in order for the encoder to output frames which are max 1390 in length? I want to stream X264 video via UDP. And also, could you point me to some docs which explains how to compile the x264 static lib with avcodec support ?

Comment: If I compile x264 with avcodec support will the static lib then have the swscale api function built in? (I don't see the header file for that anywhere in the x264 source archive.) ...Sorry, I'm new at this stuff.